# After the reinstall of Ubuntu Windows10 don't appear on the grub list boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, uefi, grub2, usb-3

I'm booting with the UEFI mode, Before the reinstall of ubuntu I had got a dual boot working perfectly on UEFI mode. But after doing a mistake on my old ubuntu (deleting some folders/files on the root...) I reinstalled a new ubuntu on the old partition of the old ubuntu.

The problem now Windows10 dont appear on the grub boot list, and when I want to boot using a bootable USB 3.0 windows10 (UEFI mode), it can't detect it. but if I turn of the UEFI mode (MBR mode), it boot on my windows bootable USB !

Here is a parte of the Boot-info of boot-repare:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi /bootmgr
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   250,069,679   250,069,679  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1      R          2,048     2,099,199     2,097,152 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2             2,099,200     2,303,999       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3             2,304,000     2,566,143       262,144 EFI System partition
/dev/sda4             2,566,144   149,889,023   147,322,880 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5           149,889,024   189,889,023    40,000,000 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda6           196,952,064   213,575,679    16,623,616 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda7      R    213,575,680   233,292,255    19,716,576 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda8      R    233,292,256   250,069,471    16,777,216 Intel Fast Flash (iFFS) partition (for Intel Rapid Start technology)
/dev/sda9           189,890,560   196,952,063     7,061,504 Data partition (Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set
```

Can you pleas help me the find fix the windows10 boot and to add it on the grub list with the actual ubuntu ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you have Windows 10 installed on an USB drive and you want to add a GRUB menu entry for that USB, this article might help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive

You'll find the GUID of the drive using `blkid` and add that to your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file.

Also stated in there, plugging in the USB and booting to Ubuntu and running `sudo update-grub` may work as well.

Comment: No ! Windows already exist on my computer ssd (take a look at sda1, sda2, sda3 and sda4). I spoke about the USB to just explain the situation.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. In that case, what is the result of `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic          
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-73-generic                
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-73-generic       
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration           
Done

Answer (score 0):

Your [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (ESP; `/dev/sda2` for you) doesn't seem to have the Windows boot loader file, `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. You should check that in Ubuntu to be it's not simply an omission in the Boot Info Script excerpts you've provided. (In Ubuntu, the file should be `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` -- but note that the ESP uses FAT, which is case-insensitive, so everything from `EFI` on could vary in case).

If this analysis is correct, then something has deleted the `bootmgfw.efi` file, and you must restore it. If you have a backup, that may be the easiest way to recover -- just restore that file, or better yet, the entire `EFI/Microsoft` directory tree from the ESP. If you don't have a backup, then you'll need to use Windows recovery tools. There's probably a good, concise Windows-specific procedure for doing this, but I don't have any pointers to such a procedure. If you can find nothing else, check [here.](http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt-part-2/) This is part of a procedure for converting Windows from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting, so it's not exactly what you need to do; but the sections entitled "Copy Windows Boot Files" (you'll need to copy from a Windows installation DVD), "Boot Into Linux," and "Setup the UEFI System Partition" *should* do the job. (Be aware that Ubuntu mounts the ESP at `/boot/efi`, so you shouldn't need to mount it as described on that page, but you will need to adjust the paths appropriately.) Also, you'll need to re-run `update-grub` to get GRUB to notice the newly-restored Windows boot loader.